# Can Realm handle inheritance of Object?

Tags: database, realm

I'm considering to use Realm as DB of private development.
So I want to know Realm can handle inheritance of Object like iOS's CoreData, or not.

CoreData supports inheritance of Object, so it is very easy to create File-system-like structure.

For example,

- FileSystemObject : Object

  - name : String
  - parent : Folder
- Folder : FileSystemObject

  - children : [FileSystemObject]
- File : FileSystemObject

  - content : Blob

Such structure is easy to create and handle in CoreData.
Can Realm create and handle such structure natively and easily?

Needless to say, Realm is just a database, so I can realize this if I divide the object to multiple table and treating them as single object by self-coding.

But my main concern is reducing structure design and amount of coding, so I want to know Realm can handle this natively...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only for code sharing and not polymorphism. Realm considers each subclass to be a completely unrelated type, which means that in your example a `List<FileSystemObject>` would only be able to store actual `FileSystemObject` objects and not `Folder` or `File` objects, which is probably not what you want. Your class hierarchy in Realm would have to look something like:

```
class FileSystemObject : Object {
    dynamic var name: String
    dynamic var parent: Folder?

    dynamic var kind: Int
    dynamic var file: File?
    dynamic var folder: Folder?
}

enum FileSystemObjectKind: Int {
    case File, Folder
}

class File : Object {
    dynamic var content: NSData
}

class Folder : Object {
    let children = List<FileSystemObject>()
}
```